# Is it possible to replace a negative "look around" in a regular expression with something that doesn't use a look-behind?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, v8

I have a regex that matches a single character `x` but not `xx`.

```
(?<!x)x(?!x)
```

This works great, the problem is the regex engine in firefox doesn't support look-behinds.  (this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665))

Is there any way to rewrite this so it doesn't use a looking behind?

edit:

the solution in the duplicate link doesn't work in this case.  If I replace the negative look-behind with

```
(?!^x)x(?!x)
```

It doesn't match correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround:

```
^(?:^|[^x])x(?!x)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ag3YUR/1)

It matches `x` if preceded by beginning of line or by a non-x

Answer (score 1):

You could use non-capturing groups:

```
(?:[^x]|^)(x)(?:[^x]|$)
```

This means we search single "x" symbol in some string. Yes, the regex matches three symbols, but we can refer to match x as $1.